# I am having trouble with the 'shimmer' CSS animation

Tags: html, css, animation

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5r19aban/1/

Basically, I would like the square to have the 'shimmer' CSS effect, but when I make the tags span instead of div, the animation slows down. I really want the square to be in-line with the text beside it though.

Could anyone help me fix this problem? I can't use div because I don't want a line break afterwards!

Thank you!

```css
.shimmer{
    /* styling stuff */
    font-size:36px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.shimmer {
  /* the shimmer magic */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(#008000),to(#008000),color-stop(.5,#fff));
  background: -moz-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(#008000),to(#008000),color-stop(.5,#fff));
  background: gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(#008000),to(#008000),color-stop(.5,#fff));
  -webkit-background-size: 25px 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 25px 100%;
  background-size: 25px 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation-name: shimmer;
  -moz-animation-name: shimmer;
  -webkit-animation-name: shimmer;
  animation-name: shimmer;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-color: #006400;
}

@-moz-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}

@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}
mark.green {
color:#006400;
font-size:36px;
background: none;
}

mark.yellow {
color:#e6e600;
font-size:36px;
background: none;
}

mark.red {
color:#ff0000;
font-size:36px;
background: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="shimmer">∎</span> ILS <br>
<span class="shimmer">∎</span> PAC <br>
<span class="shimmer">∎</span>  SIP2 <br>
<span class="shimmer">∎</span>  Cloud Library <br><br>
```

Comment: This has probably something to do with the widths. `div` takes the full width of the parent element, but a `span` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `div`, just set `.shimmer`'s `display` property to be `inline-block`. You can also change `*-animation-duration` to make the animation faster or slower:

```css
.shimmer {
  /* styling stuff */
  font-size: 36px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
}
.shimmer {
  /* the shimmer magic */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#008000), to(#008000), color-stop(.5, #fff));
  background: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#008000), to(#008000), color-stop(.5, #fff));
  background: gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#008000), to(#008000), color-stop(.5, #fff));
  -webkit-background-size: 25px 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 25px 100%;
  background-size: 25px 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation-name: shimmer;
  -moz-animation-name: shimmer;
  -webkit-animation-name: shimmer;
  animation-name: shimmer;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-color: #006400;
}
@-moz-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}
@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}
mark.green {
  color: #006400;
  font-size: 36px;
  background: none;
}
mark.yellow {
  color: #e6e600;
  font-size: 36px;
  background: none;
}
mark.red {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 36px;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="shimmer">∎</div>ILS
<br>
<div class="shimmer">∎</div>PAC
<br>
<div class="shimmer">∎</div>SIP2
<br>
<div class="shimmer">∎</div>Cloud Library
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between div and span is that div has default display style set to block. Span display is set to inline.
When you used div it took all row length and your gradient followed in 1s from left to right. The green square was kind of blinking.
With span your span element is as width as its green square. So gradient followed this maybe 20px in 1s. You can see it very clearly.

My fix of keyframe:

```
  0% {
    background-position: 0 top;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 200px top;
  }
```

just told the gradient to go 200px from left in 1s.

```css
.shimmer{
    /* styling stuff */
    font-size:36px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.shimmer {
  /* the shimmer magic */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(#008000),to(#008000),color-stop(.5,#fff));
  background: -moz-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(#008000),to(#008000),color-stop(.5,#fff));
  background: gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(#008000),to(#008000),color-stop(.5,#fff));
  -webkit-background-size: 25px 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 25px 100%;
  background-size: 25px 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation-name: shimmer;
  -moz-animation-name: shimmer;
  -webkit-animation-name: shimmer;
  animation-name: shimmer;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-color: #006400;
}

@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 top;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 200px top;
  }
}

mark.green {
color:#006400;
font-size:36px;
background: none;
}

mark.yellow {
color:#e6e600;
font-size:36px;
background: none;
}

mark.red {
color:#ff0000;
font-size:36px;
background: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="shimmer">∎</span> ILS <br>
<span class="shimmer">∎</span> PAC <br>
<span class="shimmer">∎</span>  SIP2 <br>
<span class="shimmer">∎</span>  Cloud Library <br><br>
```